# Get postal code from geo location in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, postal-code

Is it possible to find the nearest postal code using geo location search? Say, if I have lat/lng data to a house, can I get the postal code of said house using the Google Maps API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know it is not always possible with google.maps.Geocoder (or Geocoding API), but often result contains postal code, it depends on country.